# < is unexpected without a reason

Tags: batch-file

```
:deleteaccount
cls
echo what account do you want to delete?
set /p dan=
if not exist %~dp0\database\%dan%\ (
    echo this account doesn't exist & pause >nul & goto stage
    )
else %~dp0\database\%dan%\ (
    cls & echo password:
    set /p dap=
    call %~dp0\database\%dan%\%dan%.bat
    if %dap% == %rpassword1% (
        echo are you sure you want to delete this account? yes/no
        set /p daq=
        if %daq% == yes (
            @RD /S /Q %~dp0\database\%daq%\
            echo account succesfully deleted
            pause >nul & goto stage)
        if %daq% == no (goto stage)
    )
)
```

After I type the correct password for the account I wanted to delete, it says `< is unexpected` for some reason.

Comment: **Your code is not valid!**, line `8` must be moved up onto the line above as a continuation of line `7`

Comment: Then, once you've done that, your next issue is that `%~dp0\database\%dan%\ ` is not a command, and will produce an error anyhow. I would advise that you just delete it, as I cannot see a purpose for it.

Comment: Is there by any chance a `<` in your password? Because there is none in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of saving screen real estate, here's an example of your script, modified to use the correct syntax and to include a logical structure.

```batch-file
@Echo Off

:DeleteAccount
ClS
Set "dan=:"
Set /P "dan=Which account do you want to remove? "
If Not Exist "%~dp0database\%dan%\" (
    Echo The account does not exist.
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
    GoTo Stage
)
ClS
If Not Exist "%~dp0database\%dan%\%dan%.bat" (
    Echo The required batch file is missing for the account.
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
    GoTo Stage
)
Set "dap="
Set /P "dap=Please enter your password: "
Call "%~dp0database\%dan%\%dan%.bat" 2> NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 (
    Echo A error occurred running the batch file.
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
    GoTo Stage
)
If "%dap%." == "%rpassword1%." (
    "%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /M "Are you sure you want to remove this account"
    If Not ErrorLevel 2 (
        RD /S /Q "%~dp0database\%daq%" 2> NUL
        If ErrorLevel 1 (
            Echo An error occurred deleting the account.
        ) Else Echo Account successfully removed.
        "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
    )
) Else (
    Echo Incorrect password.
    "%__AppDir__%timeout.exe" /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
)

:Stage
Rem Rest of code goes here.
```

Please read and review it, taking particular notice of the included double-quotes which are used to enclose and protect special characters in strings. *The first two and last two lines were included to keep this example independent, (as they were omitted from your posted snippet).*